# Issue creating instance of Django model when model uses datetime?

Tags: python, django, powershell, django-models

I am currently making a project in Django that has two models: Cards and Articles. Both cards and articles have a manager that should allow me to quickly instantiate instances of the class. For cards I have the following:

```
class CardsManager(models.Manager):
    def create_card(self, card_name, geography, player, typestatus, _weighted_strength = 0):
        card = self.update_or_create(card_name=card_name, geography=geography, player=player, typestatus=typestatus)
        return card
```

This manager works smoothly and I have no issue uploading cards. However, my article manager is a different story. This is my article manager.

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def create_article(self, title, body, cardvar, source, datetime, readthrough, author):
         article_item = self.update_or_create(title=title, body=body, card=cardvar, source=source, entry_date_time=datetime, read_through=readthrough, cardvar__card_name=cardvar, author=author)
         return article_item
```

When I try to upload an article however, say in the following fashion:

```
article_entry = Article.objects.create_article('title', 'empty body', 'test_card_var', 'The_Source', '2019-12-30 02:03:04', 0, 'author')
```

I get the following error in my Powrshell when I simply attempt 'python manage.py runserver': LookupError: No Installed app with label 'admin'.

When I attempt to run 'python manage.py makemigrations' I get another long error message whose last line is 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.'

I think the issue may have to do with something related to either 1) entry_date_time being a datetime object and passing a string (though I honestly am not sure how I'd pass a datetime object, what do they even look like) or b) the fact that cardvar is a ForeignKey pointing at the Cards model, which may not be allowed in an upload?

I really had no issues with uploading Cards but Articles has given serious issues. If anyone could help me resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated, I'm still relatively new with Django and coding in general.

EDIT:
My Settings.py looks as follows:

```
"""
Django settings for newspaper_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
#import django_heroku
#import psycopg2
#import dj_database_url
#import dotenv 
#import psycopg2

#import dj_database_url, psycopg2


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


#DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

#conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ***********************

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #3rd party
    'crispy_forms', #new

    #Local
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig', #new 
]

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York' #new
USE_TZ = True #TESTING THIS OUT

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'newspaper_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #new 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'newspaper_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser' #new
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' #new

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**************************************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TILS = True
```

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py`

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to include settings.py